# Pandas dataset count

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01 |
| A | 02 |
| B | 03 |
| B | 04 |
| C | 05 |
| D | NaN |

If use

```
df.ColA.value_counts()
```

the result is

| ColA |  |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |

How can I get

| ColA |  |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0 |

Comment: Please don't fill your post with junk; the reason it wants your post to be a certain length is precisely because we don't want questions like this with no discussion of what you have searched for or what you already know. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby` `ColA` and `count` `ColB`, which will exclude missing values:

```
df.groupby('ColA', as_index=False)['ColB'].count()
```

Output:

```
  ColA  ColB
0   A      2
1   B      2
2   C      1
3   D      0
```